# SharePoint 2010 Reusable workflow not listed in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, workflow

I have created SharePoint 2010 workflow by using SharePoint Designer on SharePoint online site. Then I saved that workflow as .wsp using Save As Template option from SPD.

When I deployed that solution back to another site (same subscription) and activated the feature and try to add that workflow to list using Workflow setting option, the workflow is not listed for any content type i.e. list, item and folder etc.

Did anyone face problem like this? I am just trying to use the SP 2010 workflow to send an email to the external user.

Comment: I think you have not selected "Allow management of content types"* to Yes on your new list. Please ensure that.